# How to sort with typeorm?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

The database contains the following data:

```
[
  {id: 1, username: "test", amount: 2},
  {id: 2, username: "example", amount: 0},
  {id: 3, username: "hello", amount: 1},
  {id: 4, username: "fsa", amount: 0},
  {id: 5, username: "aas", amount: 10},
]
```

now i need to query with typeorm to retrieve the data but i need to get it sorted according to amount field and with limit only 3 users, so i should get this:

```
 [
      {id: 5, username: "aas", amount: 10},
      {id: 1, username: "test", amount: 2},
      {id: 3, username: "hello", amount: 1},
    ]
```

how to make that query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `find` method following solution works. Check out TypeORM's documentation for [find options](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options) for more information and other options.

```
userRepository.find({
        take: 3,
        order: {
            amount: "ASC" // "DESC"
        }
    }
```